# Lobstr vault keys and lobstr

Tags: multi-sig

I have a lobstr account.  I installed vault. It put key in lobstr signers but it has never connected vault properly so the signer is there but I can't sign anything.  Now to be honest I uninstalled vault thinking there must be a glitch somewhere.  I stupidly created new and not recover.  I have my original pass phrase and now when I try and recover it gives me a brand new key not the original one.  So I can look at lobstr,  just can't do anything because it doesn't have correct key and I can't get original one in.  Ive tried all help articles ive contacted support every day for three weeks. At this point I want to remove all signers except lobstr one so I can get my account back. Can it be done in stellar laboratory? If so how??. Step by step so I dont lock me out forever. I can't be the only one who's done this. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

As you have the original recovery phrase from lobstr vault you can restore that account.

- Delete and re-install lobstr vault
- follow the steps to recover an existing account

It should show you that lobstr vault is a signer for one account. If that went well head over to lobstr and send any transaction. Afterwards you should have a pending transaction to confirm inside lobstr vault. For me a long time it did not show popups for new transactions.

If that does not show but you have the secret or recovery-phrase of your lobstr you can still unlock multisig manually.

In order to do that you need to compose a transactions that gives your lobstr signer enough weight to sign transactions on it's own.
First check your account (https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/).
You probably see a threshold of `20` on your account and three signers like in this [example account](https://stellar.expert/explorer/testnet/account/GBCEDNI4CR2CSHQS3HQB4YQ3XGCS4VABGQP2X7NC4JBUCQKMVU43WRIC):

[image: screenshot of GBCEDNI4CR2CSHQS3HQB4YQ3XGCS4VABGQP2X7NC4JBUCQKMVU43W on testnet showing the signers after lobstr vault was added as a signer]

If the first signer (weight 1) is missing but the other one matches your vault public key you can compose a transaction and send it off to lobstr vault API.

- open [stellar laboratoy](https://laboratory.stellar.org/#txbuilder?network=public)
- enter your account
- click 'Fetch next sequence number for account...'
- Click add operation
- Select 'Set Options'
- Enter `20` in the field 'Master Weight'. Leave everything else empty
- Click 'Sign in transaction signer'
- Enter your lobstr private key in the signer field (if you have the account imported into freighter you can sign with that - even better)
- You will see that the transaction was signer with one signer
  [image: List item]
- Copy the `XDR` from the field

You now have the XDR that is missing your vault signature. You can just send the data to vault API manually.

Open a terminal

```
$ ## you will need to paste the XDR from lab after entering the 'read' command
$ read XDR
$ curl -XPOST -d"{\"xdr\":\"${XDR}\"}" -H'content-type: application/json' 'https://vault.lobstr.co/api/transactions/'
```

Afterwards the transaction should show up in vault to sign off.